# Mixed DML occurring even in Finalizer in Queueable

Tags: apex, mixed-dml

We have a queueable framework where we have an object `AsyncRequest__c`

Fields Are : `ApexClassName__c`, `Content__c`, `AttachmentAvailable__c`, `Status__c` etc

So whenever someone wants to enqueue a job they create a record in `AsycnRequest__c` with their handlerName in `ApexClassName`.

The handler implements an interface.

```
public interface AsycnRequestHandler {

    void execute(AsyncRequest__c queueItem);

}
```

And this gets called from my Queueable class which also implements Finalizer.

```
public without sharing class QueueableasycnRequestDispatcher implements Finalizer, Queueable, Database.AllowsCallouts {

    private AsyncRequest__c  asycnRequest;

    public QueueableasycnRequestDispatcher(AsyncRequest__c  asycnRequest) {
        this.asycnRequest = asycnRequest;
    }

    public void execute(QueueableContext queueableContext) {
        QueueableasycnRequestDispatcher finalizer = new QueueableasycnRequestDispatcher(asycnRequest);
        System.attachFinalizer(finalizer);
        asycnRequestHandler handler = (asycnRequestHandler) Type.forName(asycnRequest.ApexClassName__c).newInstance();
        try {
            handler.execute(asycnRequest);
            asycnRequest.Status__c = asycnRequestConstants.QUEUE_STATUS_COMPLETE;
        } catch (Exception objException){
            asycnRequest.Status__c = asycnRequestConstants.QUEUE_STATUS_FAILED;
            asycnRequest.Error__c = 'Failed with exception => ' + objException.getMessage() + ' at line ' + objException.getLineNumber() + ' with stacktrace as => ' + objException.getStackTraceString();
        }

    }


    public void execute(FinalizerContext finalizerContext) {
        if(finalizerContext.getResult() == ParentJobResult.SUCCESS && String.isNotEmpty(asycnRequest.Status__c) && !asycnRequest.Status__c.equalsIgnoreCase(asycnRequestConstants.QUEUE_STATUS_FAILED)){
            asycnRequest.Status__c = asycnRequestConstants.QUEUE_STATUS_COMPLETE;
        } else if (finalizerContext.getResult() == ParentJobResult.UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION){
            Exception objException = finalizerContext.getException();
            asycnRequest.Status__c = asycnRequestConstants.QUEUE_STATUS_FAILED;
            asycnRequest.Error__c = 'Failed with exception => ' + objException.getMessage() + ' at line ' + objException.getLineNumber() + ' with stacktrace as => ' + objException.getStackTraceString();
        }
        Database.update(asycnRequest);
        asycnRequestExecutor.execute();
    }
}
```

Now if someone tries to update Setup object in their handler's `execute`  method, the finalizer update is failing with `MIXED DML`, I ran a test class and saw the behaviour.

Isn't `Finalizer` suppose to separate the transaction? My framework was built under this assumption. For now the update `Database.update(asycnRequest);` needs to happen in future or queueable. But any other ideas or any way to detect if the transactions is already in setup object, then only execute this in Async mode.

I know I can add a try catch on the update and check for MIXED_DML text and then fire Async operation. But any other way apart from try catch?

**Updating Test class and Sample handler class**

```
@IsTest
static void testBehaviorWithSetupObject() {
    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator'];
    User u1 = new User(
            Alias = 'abc',
            Email='unit.SampleQueueItemHandler@email123.com',
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',
            FirstName='SampleQueueItemHandler',
            LastName='Test',
            LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
            LocaleSidKey='en_GB',
            ProfileId = p.Id,
            TimeZoneSidKey='Europe/London',
            Username='SampleQueueItemHandler@testVs3.com',
            IsActive=true
    );
    insert u1;
    Test.startTest();
    QueueItemUtils.createQueueItem('SampleQueueItemHandler', 'SampleQueueItemHandler', JSON.serialize(u1), 6, 'Queueable', true);
    Test.stopTest();
}
```

---

```
public with sharing class SampleQueueItemHandler implements QueueItemHandler {

    public void execute(AsycnRequest__c queueItem) {
        if(queueItem.Priority__c == 6) {
            User deserializedUser = (User) JSON.deserialize(queueItem.Content__c, User.class);
            List<User> users = [SELECT Id,FirstName FROM User WHERE Id = :deserializedUser.Id];
            System.debug('users -> '+users);
            users.get(0).FirstName = 'SampleQueueItemHandler2@testVs3.com';

            update users;
            List<User> usersAfterUpdate = [SELECT Id,FirstName FROM User WHERE Id = :deserializedUser.Id];
            System.debug('usersAfterUpdate -> '+usersAfterUpdate);
        }
    }
}
```

And the exception occurs

> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a1J0k000001IdlAEAS; first error: MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa): AsyncRequest__c, original object: User: []
> Class.QueueableasycnRequestDispatcher.execute: line 36, column 1

Which is `Database.update(queueItem);` in Finalizer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two problems.

First, you must attach the Finalizer before doing anything that might crash; ideally, this means your Finalizer should be in the first few lines of the execute method:

```
public void execute(QueueableContext queueableContext) {
    System.attachFinalizer(this);
    asycnRequestHandler handler = (asycnRequestHandler) Type.forName(asycnRequest.ApexClassName__c).newInstance();
    try {
        // ...
```

See the examples in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_transaction_finalizers.htm).

Second, in a unit test, you may need to use System.runAs to separate normal DML from Setup DML. While it's true that the Finalizer will run in a separate transaction, whatever you're doing wrong has nothing to do with this Finalizer.

Note that you already have a try-catch block, so theoretically, nothing short of governor limits should break your code anyways.

---

Edit: A try-catch is still needed to prevent the test from failing:

```
@IsTest
static void testBehaviorWithSetupObject() {
    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='System Administrator'];
    User u1 = new User(
            Alias = 'abc',
            Email='unit.SampleQueueItemHandler@email123.com',
            EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',
            FirstName='SampleQueueItemHandler',
            LastName='Test',
            LanguageLocaleKey='en_US',
            LocaleSidKey='en_GB',
            ProfileId = p.Id,
            TimeZoneSidKey='Europe/London',
            Username='SampleQueueItemHandler@testVs3.com',
            IsActive=true
    );
    insert u1;
    Test.startTest();
  try {
    QueueItemUtils.createQueueItem('SampleQueueItemHandler', 'SampleQueueItemHandler', JSON.serialize(u1), 6, 'Queueable', true);
    Test.stopTest();
  } catch(Exception e) {
  // Check the results here
  }
}
```

Comment: I wanted the code to break in test. Because in  real world scenario, a user can be updated in execute, so will that fail? or it it only test class which fails and in real world things will work fine?

Comment: That finalizer change was the first thing that jumped out at me as well.

Comment: @NagendraSingh We need to see your unit test code to provide specific guidance, but you should be able to get it to work correctly. I'll write up a quick demo for you.

Comment: From Test the code does break `System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a1J0k000001IdlAEAS; first error: MIXED_DML_OPERATION, DML operation on setup object is not permitted after you have updated a non-setup object (or vice versa): AsyncRequest__c, original object: User: []
Class.QueueableasycnRequestDispatcher.execute: line 36, column 1` when updating AsycnRequest__c

Comment: @NagendraSingh Did you fix the finalizer as I specified? If not, I'd expect this to be a problem.

Comment: Yes updated the finalizer. @sfdcfox

Comment: Updated my code above and added test and handler. @sfdcfox

Comment: @sfdcfox Just tested from Anonymous apex and its working even after updating a user. So it will fail from test class as test class treats asycn transction as single request, Understood

Comment: @NagendraSingh I made the unit test work, too. Apparently, you need to use a try-catch block in the unit test.

Comment: Yes in test class we need to use a try catch. Thanks for investing time and rectifying the code with your valuable suggestion.